# Set custom dimension with Google Tag Manager for Google Analytics on android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm having some issues to log custom dimensions on android with GTM. Screen and event logging work well, but the lack of documentation doesn't show how to perform this action.

```
DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();
dataLayer.pushEvent("linkOpen", DataLayer.mapOf("linkUrl", link, "sexe", "femme"));
```

Here is my implementation on GTM console :

[image]

Unfortunately, this custom dimension seems to not be sent and I can't retrieve it on the Google Analytics dashboard.

Please consider that i'm using a legacy container and not a firebase container.

I'm quite frustrated about the limited informations and examples that Google offers to show how to use GTM for mobile applications. Thanks for helping.

Comment: When you say that "this custom dimension seems to not be sent", do you mean that you don't see it showing up in the calls being made, or in the data in GA? You also reference linkURL - is that being called successfully? Can you show a screenshot of have you have defined {{sexe}}?